# Can't use the add function on a dictionary

Tags: c#

I've been trying to make a simple dictionary, then tried to add some elements to it in c# and have followed the syntax used in this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019

However I get an error; "The name 'myDictionary.Add()' does not exist in this current context."
Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting this issue?

It might be worth noting that I am working with Unity, although I don't see how it would make a difference in this case.

Heres the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class myClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    myDictionary.Add("key", "value");
}
```

Comment: You can't just put code in the root of a class, it needs to be inside a method.

Comment: You need to put the `Add` statement within a method or the constructor, alternatively declare the dictionary with `Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value" }};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just put code in the root of a class, it needs to be inside a method. For example:

```
public class myClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // This is a method...
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        myDictionary.Add("key", "value");
    }
}
```